# Insert data psql user table

Tags: psql

I created psql table with below command

```html
CREATE TABLE users(
 user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 username VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 password VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 email VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 last_login TIMESTAMP
);
```

but I cannot insert any data

```html
INSERT INTO users(user_id , username, password, email, created_on) VALUES(0, ’user999’, ‘mypassword’, ‘hello@mymail.com’,'2016-03-04','2016-01-01');
```

[image]

Comment: check whether your column names and values are correct .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this query then remove the last login date because you have mentioned less field.

```
INSERT INTO users(user_id , username, password, email, created_on) VALUES(0, ’user999’, ‘mypassword’, ‘hello@mymail.com’,'2016-03-04');
```

Or you have to mentioned `last_login` in your query.

```
INSERT INTO users(user_id , username, password, email, created_on,last_login) VALUES(0, ’user999’, ‘mypassword’, ‘hello@mymail.com’,'2016-03-04','2016-01-01');
```

or you can simply use it.

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES(0, ’user999’, ‘mypassword’, ‘hello@mymail.com’,'2016-03-04','2016-01-01');
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I tried all commands but still, error is there <br/><img src="http://gdurl.com/JDND" width="300" height="143">

Comment: https://github.com/asimkh/apps/tree/hazzir</br>I am working on local mac machine to setup psql database

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vagrant with laravel 5.2 with psql at your local machine e.g. mac.

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ psql -U homestead -h localhost
```

Use homestead for database connection and psql tables e.g.

```
DATABASE_URL
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

This will connect your vagrant or server correctly with psql database connection.